# The method setAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type WebElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

This is my code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("input_17")).setAttribute("value", "selected");
```

Getting the error

> "The method setAttribute(String, String) is undefined for the type
>   WebElement" when I try to change Attribute of webelement.

But for "`getAttribute`" it is not giving any error.

Comment: can you please share the whole code, so that we can understand what are you trying to do?

Comment: Selenium doesn't have setAttribute method, it is a method of javaScriptExecutor

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) `WebElement` doesn't have `setAttribute` method.
But you could do this using [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html):

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('input_17').setAttribute('value', 'selected')");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .sendkeys instead

```
driver.findElement(By.id("input_17")).sendKeys("your value");
```